# Apple Script - GetElementByID value Math.random()

Tags: javascript, variables, applescript, getelementbyid

I'm using Apple Script for adding values on a website's form. But I'm trying to generate an random e-mail address like "abc**123***@gmail.com". In this case the number should be randomly picked by JavaScript, but I’m struggling with my code.

It looks like:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementByID('entry_field_4').value = 'abc+var = math.random(100,199)+@gmail.com';" in document 1
```

Do anyone know a possible solution?

Thanks mates!

Best
pxlicious

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_number_between_two_values

Comment: It’s `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`, and `Math`, not `math`. Also, your string concatenation syntax is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Safari"
  set min to 100
  set max to 199
  set jsCode to "document.getElementById('entry_field_4').value = 'abc' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (" & max & " - " & min & " + 1)) + " & min & ") + '@gmail.com';"
  do JavaScript jsCode in front document
end tell
```

This assumes you have a web page open in *Safari* which contains a [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) tag in its markup. Something like the following:

```
<input id="entry_field_4" type="email">
```

**Notes:**

1. The AppleScript/JavaScript code above includes the following part which generates a random number:

   ```
   (Math.floor(Math.random() * (" & max & " - " & min & " + 1)) + " & min & ")
   ```

   Further explanation of that line of code can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive).
2. The AppleScript variables `min` and `max` can be `set` to your preferred range of numbers. Currently the `min` value is set to `100` and the `max` value is set to `199`. This means that the random number generated will be `>= 100` and `<= 199`.

   This will result in the `<input>` tag with a `id` of `entry_field_4` being populated with the desired email address. For example, it may be any of the following:

   - `abc100@gmail.com`
   - `abc123@gmail.com`
   - `abc167@gmail.com`
   - `abc199@gmail.com`
   - etc...